# Como fixar imagem da câmera independente da posição do device ? Objective - C

Tags: ios, câmera, landscape

Eu estou trabalhando num aplicativo que através da câmera, ele detecta o rosto das pessoas em tempo real e troca a imagem do rosto por uma máscara qualquer. (Basicamente o SquareCam)

Porém ele só funciona com o dispositivo na vertical (portrait).

Quando eu coloco na horizontal(landscape), a máscara não se forma no rosto.

Então eu gostaria de espelhar a imagem na posição que dá certo (portrait) para qualquer posição que o device tivesse. Como eu faço para poder travar/fixar a posição da câmera ?

Comment: Você disse que a mascara não se forma, mas você consegue detectar o rosto mesmo com o device em landscape? Se sim, provavelmente você precisa corrigir a posição da máscara quando a orientação muda.

Comment: Não detecta o rosto quando ta em landscape.

Comment: Você já tentou carregar o seu app com o device já em landscape e ir até a tela de captura sem mudar a orientação? As vezes na troca de orientação, faltou verificar se o delegate que te retorna o sample buffer da camera está funcionando.